# On a map where each point on the map is given a value then is finding the n non-overlapping submaps to minimize the range of sums known to be P or NP?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

To be more specific because of the character limit : "If there is a continuous graph where each vertex on the graph is assigned a positive integer value then is the goal of finding the n continuous non-overlapping subgraph that minimize the range of sums of the vertices of the subgraph known to P or NP for 1<n<# of vertices"
Here is an example graph: https://www.desmos.com/geometry/zfklxdlnew
In that graph there are 3 subgraphs that minimize the range, totaling to 18, 20 and 19 with a range of 3.
All vertices in the graph must be included in 1 and only of the subgraphs.

Comment: Post text has significantly larger character limit, can you please write the problem in more details? What is "continuous graph" here, what maps are you talking about (from where to where?), and so on.

Comment: My guess is that "continuous" is supposed to be "connected" and "map" is supposed to be "graph". But ideally there would be no guessing what the question means.

Comment: Yah map is supposed to be graph, I couldn't write graph because of the character limit.